# How do (?:) and () work together to form a regex group?

Tags: python, regex

I'm not clear on why a group is matched when it is preceded by non-capture group notation. Yet when a string is preceded by non-capture group notation it raises an error in this instance.

What is causing these two different results?

```
>>> x = re.compile(r'John\s(?:Doe)')
>>> result = x.match("John Doe")
>>> result.group()
'John Doe'
>>> result.group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: no such group
```

```
>>> x = re.compile(r'John\s(?:(Doe))')
>>> result = x.match("John Doe")
>>> result.group()
'John Doe'
>>> result.group(1)
'Doe'
```

Comment: What did you expect them to output respectively?

Comment: Your second example has two groups, the outer one which does not capture and the inner one which does.

Answer (score 0):

The `?:` operator at the beginning of the group basically says "don't remember me".  It's useful when creating regexps where you need to match multiple items but don't actually need the results.  Like `(?:foo|bar)` will match both foo and bar, but it won't be recorded in the list of groups.

So in your first example, there is no group to remember because you specified `?:` telling it not to -- thus the error for `group(1)`.

In the second, you actually double-() quote the expression for no need.  `(?:(Doe))` is basically the same as `(Doe)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on applyapplying https://regex101.com/ website i gotten this result

[image: First Case Repl]

[image: Second Case Repl]

As My conclusion, maybe it's just like an array how group work how you should think, which each nested and map itu object with number labeled as key to looking up group

`['John Doe', ['Doe']]` and it mapped itu an object and with a numberic value as key to access the target group for the second repl.